# Convert dragged item to droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Folks,
I'm using jQuery UI, simple `ol > Li` operation with draggable and droppable options.

I have two `li` items, category and subcategory.

My aim is to allow the user to drag multiple new categories and sub-categories into the exiting list.

I am able to add multiple categories and subcategories to existing list loaded at the time of document refresh. However the newly appended li category does not accept subcategory unless the page is refreshed.

```
<ol class="list">
<li class="category"> a</li>
<li class="category"> b</li>
<li class="category"> c
<ol>
<li class="subcategory"> c1</li>
<li class="subcategory"> c2</li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

I can add new *category* and *subcategory*. But let say I add new *category d*, I will like to add a *subcategory* to it. The only way it works, is that I save the state and refresh the page.

I will like user to build their entire desired list and save at the end *without having to refresh the page* multiple time in between.

so for category, I think I'm pretty close but can't get it to register to droppable object.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
  $('.list').append(ui.draggable.clone(true).detach().addClass('ui-droppable ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle'));

}
```

Jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ozzie6935/8mch0r1k/6/

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a more complete example for replication. When the item is dropped, it is not initialized as a Droppable element. You must initialize it.

Comment: You might also consider Sortable: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish from your post.

I have put together this example that might help you.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".list .subcategory").draggable();
  $(".list").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var newItem = ui.draggable.clone();
      ui.draggable.remove();
      newItem
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .removeClass('ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle')
        .attr("style", "");
      $('.list').append(newItem);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.list .category,
.list .subcategory {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ol class="list">
  <li class="category"> a</li>
  <li class="category"> b</li>
  <li class="category"> c
    <ol>
      <li class="subcategory"> c1</li>
      <li class="subcategory"> c2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Update**

Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/b28utk0r/8/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  function makeParentDrop(target) {
    $(target).droppable({
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      accept: "#draggable li.child",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        alert("dropped, do something ... ");
      }
    });
  }

  $('#draggable li.parent, #draggable li.child').draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
  });


  $('#droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: "#draggable li.parent",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.draggable.clone());
      var newItem = ui.draggable.clone(true).detach().addClass('ui-droppable ui-droppable-active ui-state-highlight');
      $('.list').append(newItem);
      makeParentDrop(newItem);

    }
  });

  makeParentDrop('#droppable li.parent');

});
```

AS the new items are not initialized as Droppable elements, you must initialize them. I have added a Function to help do that.

Comment: So I created following JSfiddle to demo the behavior. 

you will see that child is draggable to any parent, except if new parent is appended.

https://jsfiddle.net/ozzie6935/8mch0r1k/6/